# Have Windows Media Video 7 (WMV1) patents expired?

Tags: software, video, format

- the Windows Media Video 7 video coding format is [also known as WMV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video#Versions).
- WMV 7 "publicly exists" since [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video#Video_compression_formats) [[1]](https://www.computerhope.com/history/1999.htm)
- [in most jurisdictions, patents seems to be valid 20 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent)
- software patent where they are valid [still have usually the same time validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_patent) (I check that in case there was something different about them)

Comment: Patents are generally in force for 20 years from the date of application and "software patent" is not a separate category with special treatment regarding length of term.

Comment: If you know the particular patents by their number, we can check their status. Otherwise it makes it a lot of work to track them down.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC-1

Comment: «"software patent" is not a separate category with special treatment regarding length of term.» Thanks, I just mentioned and check that i case there was a different duration for that.

Comment: @EricShain «If you know the particular patents by their number» Does it happen to have software patents enter in application after (a year or more) the publication of software using them? The hope is that it's possible to have a first step with a reasonable certainly of legal safety of the format based only on the format introduction date. Only for small projects. My actual goal needs more legal safety. Thanks for your guidance, I'll try to explore (and maybe ask on this forum) to get the list the patents.

Comment: VC-1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC-1#WMV3 «WMV3 bitstreams fully VC-1 compliant» That indeed helps about WMV3 (WMV 9) because VC-1 patents are well documented. In the article, the patent section is sourced by an MPEG-LA document that is even updated regularly with expired patents. That's very convenient. So when MPEG-LA will list all of them expired for VC-1, then WMV3(WMV 9) will also become "clean". However I can't find such a strong link between WMV3 => WMV2 and WMV2 => WMV1. Strong as in one being a superset of the other.

Comment: As George White said, there is no separate category of patents for software. Typically patent applications publish 18 months after filing. Software can be published anytime after filing, but isn't always within a fixed time period. The problem is there are often many patents. Sometimes with different owners. Patents that are for  improvements can be filed years after the initial patents. Generally speaking for something has been public for over 20 years it is likely the initial patents have expired. Usually technologies are improved over time and those improvements may still be under patent.